# While loop more efficient than vectorised function

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, performance, while-loop

I'm attempting to estimate the value of π using random numbers. Initially, I used an approach where I generate 1,000,000 random numbers and count how many of them fall inside a unit circle to estimate π. However, when using a while loop, I obtain more precise estimates of π with a smaller number of draws. Why does this while loop approach yield more accurate results with a smaller number of draws compared to the initial approach with a fixed number of draws?

Initial code with 1,000,000 draws:

```py
def pi_estimation1(n):
    # Create a random number generator
    rng = np.random.default_rng()

    # Generate x and y coordinates simultaneously
    coordinates = rng.random((n, 2))

    # Use vectorized operations (UFunc) to filter points inside and outside the circle
    x_in_circle = coordinates[coordinates[:, 0]**2 + coordinates[:, 1]**2 <= 1]
    x_out_circle = coordinates[coordinates[:, 0]**2 + coordinates[:, 1]**2 > 1]

    

    # Calculate the value of pi based on the ratio of points inside the circle
    pi = 4 * len(x_in_circle) / n
    return pi, x_in_circle, x_out_circle,n

# Example of usage
estimated_pi, x_in_circle, x_out_circle,n = pi_estimation1(1000000)
# # Plot points inside and outside the circle
plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
plt.scatter(x_in_circle[:, 0], x_in_circle[:, 1], color='blue')
plt.scatter(x_out_circle[:, 0], x_out_circle[:, 1], color='red')
plt.show()

print("The estimated value of pi is ", estimated_pi)
print("The exact value of pi is ", np.pi)
print("The error relative to the exact value is ", abs(estimated_pi - np.pi) / np.pi)
print("Number of points ",n)
```

Results :

```
The estimated value of pi is  3.140236
The exact value of pi is  3.141592653589793
The error relative to the exact value is  0.0004318362497579398
Number of points  1000000
```

Code with while loop:

```py
def pi_estimation_while_loop(deviation):
    
    # Initialize variables
    pi = 0
    n = 0
    dev=1
    in_circle = 0
    
    rng=np.random.default_rng()
    
    # Loop until the deviation is less than 0.0001
    while deviation < dev :
        coordinate = rng.random((1, 2))
        if coordinate[0,0]**2 + coordinate[0,1]**2 <= 1:
            in_circle += 1
        
    
        n += 1
        pi = 4 * in_circle / n
        dev=(abs(pi-np.pi)/np.pi)
        #
        
        
        
    return pi, n, dev

pi, n, dev = pi_estimation_while_loop(1e-9)
print("The estimated value of pi is ", pi)
print("The exact value of pi is ", np.pi)
print("The error relative to the exact value is ", abs(pi - np.pi) / np.pi)
print("The number of iterations is ", n)
```

Results:

```
The estimated value of pi is  3.141592654644592
The exact value of pi is  3.141592653589793
The error relative to the exact value is  3.3575292254192973e-10
The number of iterations is  499581
```

I'm wondering about possible reasons for this difference in accuracy between the two approaches and how to optimize the estimation of π with the minimum number of draws. Any help or explanation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: For an apples to apples comparison, change your loop to operate the same number of times as the number of points chosen by your vectorized code (or vice versa), and seed the random number generator with the same number before both calls. (Pseudo-)Random numbers are, by their nature, pseudo-random, so taking more numbers will not necessarily make your result more accurate. See https://www.online-python.com/jWPtagD0RQ, where I modified your code to do what I said and they both give the same estimated pi

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought that the precision depended exclusively on the number of draws and very little on the seed, given the uniform nature of random draws. I thought that by increasing the number of draws, precision would go hand in hand.

Comment: `while deviation < dev:` Your while loop condition is using pi. That's not realistic - the only reason why you would write a loop like this is if you didn't know the quantity you're estimating. By definition, in order for your while loop to terminate, the estimate must be close to pi. That's why it's more accurate than a fixed number of trials.